# How can I solve java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Mod11Check$ProcessingDirection

Tags: java, hibernate, weblogic, pom.xml

i m trying to deploy a java 11 application on Weblogic 14.1.1 but a get an error.
I have tryed to add this depencies but didnt work.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

I'm updating this app from java 8 to java 11.
The error seem to show up after change the log4j dependency from

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Someone know how to solve this error?

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Mod11Check$ProcessingDirection
    at com.oracle.classloader.PolicyClassLoader.findClass(PolicyClassLoader.java:399)
    at com.oracle.classloader.PolicyClassLoader.loadClass(PolicyClassLoader.java:372)
    at com.oracle.classloader.weblogic.LaunchClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:55)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2309)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType$1.run(AnnotationType.java:112)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType$1.run(AnnotationType.java:109)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.<init>(AnnotationType.java:109)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.getInstance(AnnotationType.java:85)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:267)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:227)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.lambda$parseAnnotationArray$2(AnnotationParser.java:736)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArrayElements(AnnotationParser.java:747)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotationArray(AnnotationParser.java:735)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:538)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:356)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:287)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:121)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:73)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3757)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3746)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getAnnotations(Class.java:3682)
    at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.AnnotationAncestry.isExtendedAnnotationDeep(AnnotationAncestry.java:107)
    at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.AnnotationAncestry.isExtendedAnnotation(AnnotationAncestry.java:93)
    at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos$Cache.getAnnotationsOfInterest(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:899)
    at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos$Cache.access$600(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:867)
    at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.getAnnotatedClassesByTargetsAndSources(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:683)
    at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.hasAnnotatedClasses(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:732)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIUtils.hasCDIEnablingAnnotations(CDIUtils.java:835)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIUtils.isWebModuleCDIEnabled(CDIUtils.java:411)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIUtils.isModuleCdiEnabled(CDIUtils.java:661)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIModuleExtensionFactory.create(CDIModuleExtensionFactory.java:39)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.createModuleExtensions(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:264)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.initDrivenObjectArray(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:232)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:107)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextStateInParallel(StateMachineDriver.java:144)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.parallelPrepare(ModuleStateDriver.java:46)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:75)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:55)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:241)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.prepare(SingleModuleDeployment.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:65)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:229)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:103)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:242)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:807)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1359)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:277)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:177)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:186)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:47)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:677)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:651)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)
```

Here the POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>          
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.22</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.2</ejbVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

i m totaly stuck right now and i cant find nothing similar to this problem.